# Make systemd-timesyncd not listen to IPv6

Tags: debian, systemd

On one of my servers (Debian 9) I disabled IPv6. Now I receive the following error in the system's syslog:

```
systemd-timesyncd[645]: Failed to setup connection socket: \
    Address family not supported by protocol
```

How can I disable IPv6 for systemd-timesyncd?

Comment: Have you specified your time server by IP address or by name? If by name, run `getent hosts <name-of-NTP-server>`. If you get an IPv6 address back, your DNS resolver library is still preferring IPv6 over IPv4 and you'll need to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a known `systemd` bug in Arch. Did not find any reference for Debian itself, but is possible there is a similar bug. From the arch wiki relevant [post](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/59806)

> systemd-timesyncd will contact servers in turn until one is found that
>   responds. Arch uses the zones in the order of 0, 1, 2, 3. However, all
>   pool.ntp.org zones only have IPv6 and IPv4 enabled on the 2 subdomain.
>   All others are IPv4 only. Therefore, 2 should be placed first in order
>   to properly provide support for IPv6/IPv4 hosts.

It is also possible DHCP is giving you a wrong NTP server.

> The following settings are configured in the "[Time]" section:
>
> NTP=
>
> A space-separated list of NTP server host names or IP addresses.
>   During runtime this list is combined with any per-interface NTP
>   servers acquired from systemd-networkd.service(8). systemd-timesyncd
>   will contact all configured system or per-interface servers in turn
>   until one is found that responds. This setting defaults to an empty
>   list.
>
> FallbackNTP=
>
> A space-separated list of NTP server host names or IP addresses to be
>   used as the fallback NTP servers. Any per-interface NTP servers
>   obtained from systemd-networkd.service(8) take precedence over this
>   setting, as do any servers set via NTP= above. This setting is hence
>   only used if no other NTP server information is known. If this option
>   is not given, a compiled-in list of NTP servers is used instead.

Possible workaround: disabling `systemd-timesyncd` and installing `chrony`

Comment: Someone more familiar with systemd than myself might also suggest a systemd-timesyncd friendly workaround.